# Convert hexadecimals to readable characters

Tags: python, arduino, hex

I am receiving hexadecimal characters via serial communication. This a sample: `3c 58 34 31 34 2e 30 7c 7c 59 32 33 39 2e 30 3e`.
I am sending this over a Python script which encodes the coordinate (<X414.0||Y239.0>) into bytes(ASCII) which get automatically converted to hexadecimal.

Now I want to convert the characters received into readable characters. I have searched all over the internet forums; they're only showing how to convert from characters to hexadecimal. Help!

Comment: If the characters are ASCII, consult an ASCII table.

Comment: Are you getting those pairs one by one?  If so, `strtol(s, NULL, 16)` will convert the hexadecimal string to a number (the ASCII value). Put the character values in a buffer one after the other to reconstitute the original string.  The Serial.parseInt() routine comes close to doing what you want, but does only decimals.

Answer (score 0):

```
input = ""    
inputReadable = bytes.fromhex(input).decode('utf-8')
```

input is the hexcode you receive.
One can create a string using the decode() method of bytes. This method takes an encoding argument, such as UTF-8, and optionally an errors argument. https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html

Comment: I appreciate your time and help but I need to decode in the arduino code thanks!